# Windows Terminal (WSL2) and M-S, C-S in Org Mode

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, terminal-emacs, wsl

UPDATE: I just tested `emacs -nw` with the MSYS2 terminal (Windows) and with iTerm (macOS) and they all have the same problem.

`emacs -nw` on WSL2 with the Windows Terminal has many known issues with key-bindings.

I've been able to find solutions for `C-w`, `C-v`, which were the first to get in my way. The fix was easy, delete *Actions* associated with those key-bindings from Windows Terminal.

Now I'm having problems with the following combos:

- `M-S-RET`

  - windows: `<M-S-return>  org-insert-todo-heading`
  - wsl: `M-RET  org-meta-return`
- `C-S-RET`

  - windows: `<C-S-return>  org-insert-todo-heading-respect-content`
  - wsl: `RET org-return`
- `C-RET`

  - windows: `<C-return> org-insert-heading-respect-content`
  - wsl: `C-j  org-return-indent`

It seems Windows Terminal is not correctly sending `M-S` and `C-S` commands to Emacs but there are no *Actions* that I can remove to fix them.

Terminology:

- windows: Emacs running natively on Windows
- wsl: Emacs running on WSL2 using Windows Terminal (no X server, i.e. `emacs -nw`)

I'm using `command-log-mode` to get what Emacs thinks the command is.

Comment: I've been using Cygwin's emacs-w32 for a while and it works rather fine _if you launch it from a proper cygwin shell_. If you're going that far, I'm sure emacs-nox works fine from MinTTY.